# Dell AIO 5400 Brightness Control on Debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, hdmi, kde, brightness

I have Dell AIO 5400 with Debian 11 installed (about to release on 18th of August). Everything works awesome, except one little thing. I can't get the brightness control work. I understand that the OS should be able to control the brightness of the AIO screen (and Windows 10 does), but on Debian I can't control it.

In /sys/class/backlight I see two directories (acpi_video0 and acpi_video1). Tried to adjust actual_brightness value in both folders but no luck.

If I specify acpi_backlight=vendor parameter in grub config after reboot the /sys/class/backlight directory is absolutely empty.

All the drivers are installed. Steam works flawlessly.

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a0d3 (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. OM3PDP3 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

lspci -v

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: Onboard - Video
        Subsystem: Dell Iris Xe Graphics
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137, IOMMU group 1
        Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        Capabilities: [320] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

lsmod | grep -i i915

```
i915                 2715648  62
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        274432  1 i915
cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
drm                   618496  17 drm_kms_helper,i915
video                  53248  2 dell_wmi,i915
```

I was told to try xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.7 and it works. So looks like there is a problem with ACPI rather than screen. But I can't figure out what parameters should I specify in Grub to get it work.

```
xrandr --listactivemonitors 
Monitors: 1
 0: +*HDMI-1 1920/527x1080/296+0+0  HDMI-1
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

An update to my research. Maybe it'll help somebody.

So when it was clarified that xrandr **can** control the brightness of my screen, I found an Arch Wiki page that clarifies mostly the same behavior of i915 module: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight#Unable_to_control_eDP_Panel_brightness_(Intel_i915_only)

According to this page I need to develop a custom Bash script with inotify-tools usage to watch for changes in actual_brightness file and pass the value to xrandr. So I modified the script a little bit and now it looks like:

```
#/bin/sh

path=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0

luminance() {
    read -r level < "$path"/actual_brightness

    # 0.01 - scaling factor
    echo "scale=2; $level * 0.01" | bc
}

xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness "$(luminance)"

inotifywait -me modify "$path"/actual_brightness | while read; do
    xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness "$(luminance)"
done
```

I put this script to autostart and it works. For example I can change the brightness through brightnessctl as it generates the MODIFY event on actual_brightness file.

```
brightnessctl -d acpi_video0 s 90
actual_brightness MODIFY
```

But in KDE control center I still can't control brightness value! KDE uses powerdevil plugin, and I don't know why, but powerdevil changes the actual_brightness file, but it doesn't generate the modify event on this file.

If I do the cat > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness I see the changes.

So there is a question. Does anybody knows how to tell powerdevil to change actual_brightness file with MODIFY event generation? Or at least use brightnessctl tool to set the brightness?

I believe there is a PowerDevil QML or any other file which can be edited to change brightness adjustment behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One more update. Tried to launch Ubuntu from USB stick and brightness controls work in there.

There is "/sys/class/backlight/**dell_uart_backlight**" folder in Ubuntu. Made some investigation on Dell UART backlight kernel module. This is included in Ubuntu in **linux-oem** package, which is mostly impossible to install in Debian 11.

https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/844937/

The thing is new Dell AIO machines work on UART interface to adjust brightness. They need an appropriate driver, which is available in Ubuntu kernel (patched by Canonical), but not in Debian.

Looking forward to... I don't know build it from source code.